# Why to map entity in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

After doing some research I see that almost everyone maps its entities retrieved from the service to a (view) model in the Controller. In my opinion this gives a implementation problem. The controller is responsible for hiding/showing specific data instead of the Service/Business logic. For example, with a user object, the password field would be transferred from the service layer to the controller because it is in the entity and then the Controller has to enforce that it is hidden.

After some thoughts I came up with another way of doing it. The repository layer returns the entities. In the Service layer then the entity is mapped onto a model and for the ViewModels I make a separate partial class that extends the model to add metadata for MVC (for validation):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[MetadataType(typeof(MyClassMetadata))]
public partial class MyClass
{
  private class MyClassMetadata
  {
     [Required]
     public int Id;

     [Required]
     [StringLength(100)]
     public string Name;
  }
}
```

Secondly, when an entity needs a relational entity, for example a City needs a reference to a Country before stored in the database, it is weird to send the City back to the Service without a Country attached. This makes that retrieving the Country is going to be in the Controller. Though, in my opinion this should be an action performed by the service (maybe in conjunction with another service or repository.)

Because above is not the general practice, I’m concerned in overlooking something? When I implement it like above, will I encounter (unforeseen) probleems?

Comment: Perhaps this should be in code review? Secondly this is expected (if you are using Database First DBML mappings).

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your first question, but not second (regarding relation entity using ORM) since I lack experience with N-tier and ORM.

For your first question, it is intended to have some (view)model in the presentation layer.  It is when you has UI-specific logic such as screen position, css style, etc where it is needed to be set, view model will be useful to hold those informations.

Say that you need to retrieve 1000 requests. From among those requests, there are unsorted 300 error requests, and 200 warning requests. You need to display those requests at grid, with customized styles (such as font color in red for error requests, etc).

One simplest way is to assign the css class into each requests, and use that class to determine the style of each requests.

For the second question, I believe providing different methods such as `GetCity` and `GetCityWithCountry` will fulfill the requirements for relationship entities. But it is just my 2 cents.